# Programmatically navigate to another view controller from a different storyboard when navbar back button is clicked

Tags: swift, xcode, button, storyboard

I got an error message when navigating from `PostJobViewController1` to `JobTableViewController`. This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class PostJobViewController1: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
// Click cancel button brings user back to home screen
@IBAction func cancelPost(_ sender: Any) {
    
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
let homeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ProfJobVC") as! JobTableViewController

    self.navigationController?.present(homeVC, animated: true)

    }
}
```

The problem is, I keep on getting an error message like this:

`Thread 1: Exception: "[<UIViewController 0x7fc331c14940> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cancelToHomeButton."`

In the All Outputs area:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

And finally, in the debugger area:

```
Exception = (NSException) * "[<UIViewController 0x7fc331c14940> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cancelToHomeButton."   0x0000600000756310
name = __NSCFConstantString *   "NSUnknownKeyException" 0x00007fff80991528
reason = __NSCFString * "[<UIViewController 0x7fc331c14940> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cancelToHomeButton."   0x0000600003828a00
userInfo = __NSDictionaryI *    2 key/value pairs   0x0000600001c54340
reserved = __NSDictionaryM *    2 key/value pairs   0x000060000094a5a0
```

My main goal is just to navigate the user to `JobTableViewController` (which is in home.storyboard) when the user clicks the barButtonItem in `PostJobViewController1` (which is in a different storyboard)

Comment: That's a needle in the haystack.  What is 'ProfJobVC'?  Where is it being used?  One could take a guess.

Comment: "ProfJobVC" is the identifier of `JobTableViewController`

Comment: Are you sure your view controller classes are set up correctly in the storyboard?

Comment: Does JobTableViewController have its own navigation controller?

Comment: Yes, all of the classes are set up correctly. I was concerned about that as well, but I double checked at least five times.

Comment: And yes, `JobTableViewController` has its own navigation controller.

Comment: The whole set up of the app has a tab bar controller which controls five different navigation controllers (and storyboards). each of the navigation controllers have multiple view controllers as well.

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing the storyboard links. Seems like something is either misnamed or the classes are not set up correctly on the storyboard or the IBAction is not correctly hooked up to the button action

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this usually happens when your view controller or IBAction/Outlet isn't properly linked. It can happen when you copy over view controllers and their connections don't change.

I'd go through and check the Storyboard ID for your view controllers and then your outlets/actions on the right panel in storyboard. The error mentions "cancelToHomeButton", which I assume must be an IBAction/Outlet.

Comment: I agree ^

The error message says "cancelToHomeButton", but the IBAction is actually named "cancelPost"

Comment: just double checked and there was indeed a second outlet. however, after fixing this, the error was the same except instead of saying cancelToHomeButton, it’s saying cancelPost. thanks for your help, though

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you remove and outlet or action from your Swift file which is classed to a storyboard so,

- Click on your view controller.
- head to "Show the connections inspector" probably the last one in the inspectors
- Click on the close buttons which show the warning icon.
- This will disconnect the outlet from XML also so the error will be foosh.

[image]